# How do I stretch an iframe embed video to forcefully take the whole browser width>

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed, liquid

I already tried using width and height 100% on it, but the issue that arises is that the frame itself takes the whole width and height, but the video keeps its aspect ratio, with a large grey frame around it. Using embeds from Vimeo and Youtube works well, but this issue arises when I use a custom CDN-based video - which is what I need.

Comment: can you add the html, css and javascript to support this question so that others may observe this for themselves

Comment: Sure. Will add one right now

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `min-width: 100%` on the iframe? If the page is not full size, then it might be taking up the width of that. So you could also try: `body { height: 100vh; }`

Comment: I did. The issue that then comes up is that iframe takes the whole width and browser, but the video keeps the same size. I'll maybe add an image for comparison

Answer (score 0):

My first guess was to just make a CSS rule selecting the element inside the iFrame. But tt seems as you have to do it with Javascript and change the CSS of the loaded page in the iFrame. CSS is rarely able to do this on its own.

For more information see:
[How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's best to include all the important details in or answer rather than just providing a link. Providing a link is always a good thing to do in order to give credit, but your answer should be written in a way that does not require the reader to click the link.

Comment: Well it is a link to another StackOverflow answer. I can copy it. But this is just a duplicate of that question. But I update it.

Comment: If it's a duplicate then flag it as such. Answers should include all important details relevant to the answer within the answer text.